# Other pages do not see the layout page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working .netcore project.Admin Areas other pages do not see the layout page.I know how it works. I have also done what happened on many sites but it has not been resolved.viewstart's page code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Dosya düzeninin fotoğrafı: [image]

Comment: Can you please provide full path `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Comment: When I write it, the _layout page of the user is coming, I want the layout page for the admin

Comment: If Layout page depends on user, I would suggest an IF statement in that code. `@{ if (user.IsAdmin) Layout = "_LayoutAdmin"; else Layout = "_LayoutUser"; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just change Layout to the following url which is the layout.cshtml in `Admin` area:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```